# Why doesn't Java allow to throw a checked exception from static initialization block?

Tags: java, exception, static-initializer

Why doesn't Java allow to throw a checked exception from a static initialization block? What was the reason behind this design decision?

Comment: What kind of exception you'd like to throw in what kind of situation in a static block?

Comment: I do not want to do anything like that. I just want to know why it is mandatory to catch the checked exceptions inside the static block.

Comment: How would you expect a checked exception to be handled then?

If it bothers you, just rethrow the caught exception with throw new RuntimeException("Telling message", e);

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Java actually provides an Exception type for that situation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html

Comment: @smp7d See kevinarpe answer below, and its comment from StephenC. It is a really cool feature but it has traps !

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Because it is not possible to handle these checked exceptions in your source. You do not have any control over the initialization process and static{} blocks cannot be called from your source so that you could surround them with try-catch.

Because you cannot handle any error indicated by a checked exception, it was decided to disallow throwing of checked exceptions static blocks.

The static block must not throw **checked** exceptions but still allows unchecked/runtime-exceptions to be thrown. But according to above reasons you would be unable to handle these either.

To summarize, this restriction prevents (or at least makes it harder for) the developer from building something which can result in errors from which the application would be unable to recover.

Comment: Actually, this answer is inaccurate.  You CAN throw exceptions in a static block.  What you cannot do is to allow a *checked* exception to *propagate out of* a static block.

Comment: You CAN handle this exception, if you are doing dynamic class loading yourself, with Class.forName(..., true, ...); Granted, this is not something you come across very often.

Comment: static { throw new NullPointerExcpetion() } - this also will not compile!

Comment: @KirillBazarov a class with a static initializer that always results in an exception will not compile (because why should it?). Wrap that throw statement in an if-clause and you're good to go.

Comment: `static{
  try {
   System.out.println("Test.enclosing_method()");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   throw new NullPointerException();
  }
 }` 
 
 I am throwing a nullpointer in static ,This does compile.

Comment: @Ravisha The NullPointerException is allowed because it is a RuntimeException not a checked exception.

Comment: then why this does not compile  static{
  throw new NullPointerException();
 }

Comment: @Ravisha because in that case there is no chance for the initializer to complete normally in any case. With the try-catch there may be no exception thrown by println and therefore the initializer has a chance to complete without exception. It's the unconditional result of an exception which makes it a compile-error.

See the JLS for that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7

But the compiler may still be fooled by adding a simple condition in your case:
`static { if(1 < 10) { throw new NullPointerException(); } }`

Comment: If I can throw runtime exceptions in the static block, why

public class X {

  static {
  throw new NullPointerException();
  }
}
is not compiling?

Comment: @Thamiar - because it is thrown unconditionally, and because you haven't caught it in the static block.  See Kosi2801's comments above.

Answer (score 77):

You can work around the problem by catching any checked exception and rethrowing it as an unchecked exception.  This unchecked exception class works well as a wrapper: [`java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html).

Sample code:

```
protected static class _YieldCurveConfigHelperSingleton {

    public static YieldCurveConfigHelper _staticInstance;

    static {
        try {
            _staticInstance = new YieldCurveConfigHelper();
        }
        catch (IOException | SAXException | JAXBException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DK: Maybe your version of Java does not support this type of catch clause.  Try: `catch (Exception e) {` instead.

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but it is a really bad idea.  The unchecked exception puts the class and any other classes that depend on it *failed* state that can only be resolved by unloading the classes.  That is typically impossible, and `System.exit(...)` (or equivalent) is your only option,

Comment: @StephenC can we think that if a "parent" class fails to load, it is de facto unnecessary to load its dependent classes since your code won't work ? Could you please provide some example of a case where it would be necessary to anyway load such a dependent class ? Thanks

Comment: How about ... if the code tries to load it dynamically; e.g. via Class.forName.

Answer (score 24):

It would have to look like this (this is **not** valid Java code)

```
// Not a valid Java Code
static throws SomeCheckedException {
  throw new SomeCheckedException();
}
```

but how would ad where you catch it? Checked exceptions require catching. Imagine some examples that may initialize the class (or may not because it is already initialized), and just to draw the attention of the complexity of that it would introduce, I put the examples in another static initalizer:

```
static {
  try {
     ClassA a = new ClassA();
     Class<ClassB> clazz = Class.forName(ClassB.class);
     String something = ClassC.SOME_STATIC_FIELD;
  } catch (Exception oops) {
     // anybody knows which type might occur?
  }
}
```

And another nasty thing -

```
interface MyInterface {
  final static ClassA a = new ClassA();
}
```

Imagine ClassA had a static initializer throwing a checked exception: In this case MyInterface (which is an interface with a 'hidden' static initializer) would have to throw the exception or handle it - exception handling at an interface? Better leave it as it is.

Comment: `main` can throw checked exceptions. Obviously those cannot be handled.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: Interesting point.  In my mental model of Java, I assume the there is a "magical" (default) Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler attached to the thread running `main()` that prints the exception with stack trace to `System.err`, then calls `System.exit()`.  In the end, the answer to this question is probably: "because Java designers said so".

Answer (score 11):

> Why doesn't Java allow to throw a checked exception from a static initialization block?

Technically, you can do this.  However, the checked exception must be caught within the block.

The actual Java restriction is that a checked exception is not allowed to *propagate* out of the block.

Technically, it is also possible to allow an *unchecked* exception to propagate out of a static initializer block<sup>1</sup>.  But it is a really bad idea to do this deliberately!  The problem is that the JVM itself catches the unchecked exception, and wraps it and rethrows it as a `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

NB: that `ExceptionInInitializerError` is an `Error` not a regular exception.  You should not attempt to recover from it.

In most cases, the exception cannot be caught:

```
public class Test {
    static {
        int i = 1;
        if (i == 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Bang!");
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // stuff
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // This won't be executed.
            System.out.println("Caught " + ex);
        }
    }
}

$ java Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bang!
    at Test.<clinit>(Test.java:5)
```

There is nowhere you can place a `try ... catch` in the above to catch the `ExceptionInInitializerError`<sup>2</sup>.

In some cases you can catch it.  For example, if you triggered the class initialization by calling `Class.forName(...)`, you can enclose the call in a `try` and catch either the `ExceptionInInitializerError` or a subsequent `NoClassDefFoundError`.

However, if you attempt to **recover** from an `ExceptionInInitializerError` you are liable to run into a roadblock.  The problem is that before throwing the error, the JVM marks the class that caused the problem as "failed".  You simply won't be able to use it.  Furthermore, any other classes that depend on the failed class will also go into failed state if they attempt to initialize.   The only way forward is to unload all of the failed classes.  That *might* be feasible for dynamically loaded code<sup>3</sup>, but in general it isn't.

<sup>1 - It is a compilation error if a static block **unconditionally** throws an unchecked exception.

2 - You *might* be able to intercept it by registering a default uncaught exception handler, but that won't allow you to recover, because your "main" thread can't start.

3 - If you wanted to recover the failed classes, you would need to get rid of the classloader that loaded them.</sup>

---

> What was the reason behind this design decision?

It is to protect the programmer from writing code that throws exceptions that cannot be handled ... because there is no way for the programmer to write a handler.

As we have seen, an exception in a static initializer turns a typical application into a brick.  The best thing that the language designers can  do help the the programmer is to specified that the checked case 1s a compilation error.  Unfortunately, it is not practical to do this for unchecked exceptions as well.

---

What should you do if your code "needs" to throw exceptions in a static initializer"?

Basically, there are two alternatives:

- If (full!) recovery from the exception *within the block* is possible, then do that.
- Otherwise, restructure your code so that the initialization doesn't happen in a static initialization block (or in the initializers of static variables).  Put the initialization in a method or constructor that can be called from a regular thread.

Comment: Are there any general recommendations on how to structure code so that it does not do any static initialization ?

Comment: How do these solutions sound ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21321935/6648326 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/56575807/6648326

Comment: 1) I don't have any.  2) They sound bad.  See the comments I left on them.  But I'm only repeating what I said in my Answer above.  If you read and understand my Answer, you will know those "solutions" are not solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [Java Language Specifications](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#39245): it is stated that it is a compile time error if static initializer <strike>fails</strike> *is able to complete abruptly* with a checked exception.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though. he asked *why* it is a compile time error.

Comment: Hmm, so throwing any RuntimeError should be possible, because JLS only mentions checked exceptions.

Comment: That's right, but you'll never see as a stacktrace. That's why you need to be careful with static initialization blocks.

Comment: @EJB: This is incorrect. I just tried it out and the following code gave me a visual stacktrace: `public class Main
{
 static
 { 
  try{Class.forName("whathappenswhenastaticblockthrowsanexception");}
  catch (ClassNotFoundException e){throw new RuntimeException(e);}
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args){}
}` Output: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: whathappenswhenastaticblockthrowsanexception
 at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: whathappen...`

Comment: The "Caused by" part shows the stack trace you're probably more interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Since no code you write can call static initialization block, it is not useful to throw checked `exceptions`. If it were possible, what would the jvm do when a checked exceptions are thrown? `Runtimeexceptions` are propagated up.

Comment: Well, yes I understand the thing now. It was very silly of me to post a question like this. But alas... I can't delete it now. :( Nevertheless, +1 for your response...

Comment: @fast, Actually, checked exceptions are NOT converted to RuntimeExceptions. If you write bytecode yourself, you can throw checked exceptions inside a static initializer to your heart's content. The JVM doesn't care about exception checking at all; it is purely a Java language construct.

Answer (score 0):

For example: Spring's DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) handles the scenario which catches a checked exception and throws another unchecked exception.

```
static {
    // Load default strategy implementations from properties file.
    // This is currently strictly internal and not meant to be customized
    // by application developers.
    try {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(DEFAULT_STRATEGIES_PATH, DispatcherServlet.class);
        defaultStrategies = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not load '" + DEFAULT_STRATEGIES_PATH + "': " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: This approach the problem that the unchecked exception cannot be caught.  Instead it puts the class and any other classes that depend on it into an unrecoverable state.

Comment: @StephenC -  Could you please give a simple example in which we'd want to have a recoverable state ?

Comment: Hypothetically ... if you wanted to be able to recover from the IOException so that the application could continue.  If you want to do that, then you must catch the exception and actually handle it ... not throw an unchecked exception.

Answer (score -5):

I am able to compile throwing a checked Exception Also....

```
static {
    try {
        throw new IOException();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         // Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but you're catching it within the static block. You're not allowed to throw a checked exception from inside a static block to outside it.