# Java field initialisation to functions that throw exceptions

Tags: java

I have a problem which reduces down to considering this class:

```
class myClass
{
    static int s_int = getInteger();

    static int getInteger() throws myClassException
    {
        ...
```

Here's my problem: this will not compile since `getInteger()` throws `myClassException` and I don't have a try catch block when initialising `s_int`.

One solution, of course, would be to build a `getIntegerAndDealWithTheException()` which doesn't throw an exception and call that instead when initialising s_int. But I'd rather not as that is not so pretty: I'd rather not litter the code with stubs.

Am I missing a syntatic trick here with my initialisation of s_int?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a *static initializer*.  A static initializer is a block of code in between `static {` and `}` used to initialize `static` variables that take more code than a simple declaration and expression.

```
class myClass
{
    static int s_int;

    static
    {
       try {
          s_int = getInteger();
       } catch (myClassException e) {
          // Handle it here.
       }
    }

    static getInteger() throws myClassException
    {
        ...
```

Static initializers may not throw checked Exceptions, according to [JLS 11.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3).  To quote:

> It is a compile-time error if a class variable initializer (§8.3.2) or
>   static initializer (§8.7) of a named class or interface can throw a
>   checked exception class.

So you must catch the `Exception`, meaning that you need more than a simple declaration and expression, so a static initializer does the job here.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize static attributes inside the class `static` block.

In your case:

```
class myClass
{
    static int s_int;

    static {
        try {
            s_int = getInteger();
        } catch (myClassException e) {
            // exception handling code
        }
    }

    static getInteger() throws myClassException
    {
        ...
```

Comment: As you can see there is a big competition between the people answering questions on SO, a constant fight with the time, that is why I first provide a short answer and then extend it :)

Answer (score 1):

I will elaborate a little on what to do when you catch the exception.

The class initialization should be put inside a static initializer. As your compiler warns, you can't leave an uncaught exception inside a static initializer. You must catch it and do something with it. If you can't recover from the exception then your class is not initialized. Then you must throw an `ExceptionInInitializerError` that signals that this classes state is invalid.

```
class MyClass {
    static int s_int;

static {
    try {
        s_int = getInteger();
    catch (MyClassException e) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        // or if it is ok, s_it = some_default_value; 
    }

static int getInteger() throws MyClassException {
   ...
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070293/exception-in-static-initialization-block) you can find a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could (but probably shouldn't) use a `static` block:

```
class myClass {

    static int s_int;
    static {
        try {
           s_int = getInteger();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```

The alternative is to lazy-load the value.

```
class myClass {

    static Integer s_int = null;

    public static int getInteger() throws Exception {
        if(s_int == null) {
            s_int = /* ? */
        }
        return s_int;
    }

    public static void wtv() {
        // never refer to the static member - use the method,
        // which will lazy-load the value
        int s_int = getInteger();
    }

    public static void doSomething() {
        // never refer to the static member - use the method,
        // which will lazy-load the value
        int s_int = getInteger();
    }

}
```

... and then always refer to `getInteger()`, never directly to the static member.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider reading the chapter "Use unchecked expetions" of the book "Clean Code" from Robert C. Martin. After that I do not think you will have this kind of problem.