# Static functions and exception

Tags: java, exception

Are there any 'best practices' or do's/dont's while throwing/handling exceptions in/from static methods ? 
Or
Is there any difference in exception handling wrt static and non-static member functions ?

I could not find any such answer on the net. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

There should't be any difference between an exception in a static method vs a non-static method.

[Exceptions in static initializers are hard to handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070293/exception-in-static-initialization-block), but that's because there's nowhere for you to put the try/catch block.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the answer is NO. But there are best practices for exception handling for sure.

You might like to consult [Effective Java](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Ft8t0S4VjmwC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Joshua Bloch - Second Edition - Chapter 9 (Exceptions).