# Initialize Database in Jersey Resource

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

what is the right way to initialize my database only once?
See this example:

```
@Path("/")
public class Resource {
    private static final Map<Integer,String> data = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String>()

    public Resource() {
        data.put(1, "1");
        data.put(2, "2");
        ...
    }
}
```

For example if I delete entry 1, it will be present on the next request again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static initialization:

```
@Path("/")
public class Resource
{
    private static final Map<Integer,String> data;
    static
    {
        myMap = new new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String>();
        myMap.put(1, "1");
        myMap.put(2, "2");
    }
}
```

The static block only gets called once, when the class is constructed.

Comment: That's it, thanks! Together with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070293/exception-in-static-initialization-block and rethrowing an exception the solution