# use try catch in static initialization block

Tags: java

I am not throwing any exception out of `static` block.

```
static 
{
    try
    {
        int number = Integer.parseInt("2a");
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        //log
    }
}
```

Why using try and catch is considered wrong in this case?

Comment: your question is answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070293/exception-in-static-initialization-block

Comment: Who says it is considered wrong? It's not necessarily always wrong.

Comment: That is about why static blocks can not throw exception. I understand that. I am not throwing any exception here.

Comment: I agree with @Jesper, why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: @MarounMaroun actually I asked a question, and some one commented there. But I found my mistake. That was a silly one, so deleted the question :)

Comment: Actually, this question is NOT answered at the link provided by @Stultuske at all.

Comment: perhaps the answer lies in "when static blocks execute?" and "How a static block is initialized?"

Comment: @Batty Could you please indicate why "using try and catch is considered wrong" and by who? I personally haven't heard this argument before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The static block must not throw checked exceptions but still allows unchecked/runtime-exceptions to be thrown.

That said, there's nothing inherently wrong about using a try catch in a static block. As stated above, this is actually a requirement if the code throws a checked exception.

Answer (score 4):

`You cannot throw Checked Exceptions in Static block`

In methods, an exception can be handled by either passing through the Exception or handling it. But in a static block code, you cannot handle exceptions this way.

Generally a clean way to handle it is using a try-catch block but here since we dont have this option lets look at the available three options.

**First:** After logging the exception throw a RuntimeException which will end the current thread (unless caught by code instantiating / calling a static method on the class for the first time).

**Second** is calling System.exit(1) but this is not desirable in a managed environment like a servlet. This option is only for java applications and only if the static initializer block performs some critical (without which the program cannot be run successfully) function like loading the database driver.

**Third** and final option is to set a flag indicating failure. Later the constructors can check the flag and throw exceptions or retry in rare cases.

Finally, if the operation is not important to the functioning of the program then maybe a simple log entry is all that is required.

for more detail about static blocks go through [this](http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/static-blocks.php) link.

Comment: Yes, you can throw them, so long as you catch them.  Exactly as OP is doing here.  What you can't do is throw them out of the static block.  But that's irrelevant, because it's not what OP is doing.