# Exception does not catching in try..catch(Exception ex)

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native-code, unsatisfiedlinkerror, system-properties

Testing presence of **videeditor_jni** Native Library in system libraries by

```
static {
    try {
        if (System.getProperty("videoeditor_jni") != null) {
            System.loadLibrary("videoeditor_jni");
        } else {
            PreferenceManager.setLibraryFlag(false);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        PreferenceManager.setLibraryFlag(false);
    }

}
```

while running this code i've got UnsatisfiedException on library in logcat.
though I've put conditions and try..catch it is checking if condition and then **Force Close**. why didn't go into catch?? any reason? tried **UnsatisfiedException, RuntimeException, Exception, Error** but not anything called in catch.. need help .

Comment: Comment this   PreferenceManager.setLibraryFlag(false); And try e.printStackTrace()

Comment: tried that..also trie to log and debug also..but still not reached at catch..,

Comment: Make your method unstatic, read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070293/why-doesnt-java-allow-to-throw-an-exception-from-static-initialization-block) for more info

Comment: give the exception stack-trace you get, and tell us which line in the code you showed here is which line-number in your code

Comment: @Strider he is not trying to throw an exception from the static block, he is trying to catch it in there, which is fine.

Comment: Just as an info: **UnsatisfiedLinkError** is not a child class of **Exception**, so it is normal if you just use the generic **Exception** not to catch **UnsatisfiedLinkError**.

Comment: @hoijui you are right, I misunderstood the question, my bad ;)

Answer (score 0):

To Catch exception stackTrace use method printStackTrace(). like as belows

write this Application class onCreate method.

```
public void onCreate()
    {
super.onCreate();
....

        try {
            if (System.getProperty("videoeditor_jni") != null) {
                System.loadLibrary("videoeditor_jni");
            } else {
                PreferenceManager.setLibraryFlag(false);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace.
        }

    }
```

Comment: tried this. returned from if condition..not moving ahead or didn't reach catch clause. even not printing log at catch and not reachable by debug mode.

Comment: try to execute this on Application class onCreate()

Comment: @pravin Sharma Putting these conditions in Appliction onCreate() is always going to else condition though it sholt go to if condition because **videoeditor_jni** is present and working .

Comment: if its present then it must be execute in static and non static both block.

Comment: in both conditions static and nonstatic 
**System.getProperty("videoeditor_jni") ** returns null . somewhere it loads successfully because it is used ahead and working well. can't understand why System.getproperty returns null